# Visual studio C# VSTO: Refactoring

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, vsto

Coming from Visual basic, I kind of miss the With statement that is lacking in C#, I'm looking for ways to refactor the code so it's not so crowded.

I have the following code:

```
Globals.Ribbons.RibbonMain.chkCalculation.Checked = (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Calculation == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic);
Globals.Ribbons.RibbonMain.chkScreenUpdating.Checked = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating;
Globals.Ribbons.RibbonMain.chkEvents.Checked = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.EnableEvents;
Globals.Ribbons.RibbonMain.chkDisplayAlerts.Checked = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DisplayAlerts;
```

How can I extract the common denominators to trim down the code to make it more legible?

What I thought is creating the 2 variables below, but i don't know the variable type I should use. Is there somewhere I could look for the variable type?

```
variableType R = Globals.Ribbons.RibbonMain
variableType A = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
```

Comment: C# has the `var` keyword, which will infer the type from the initialization expression. Then Visual Studio has a code fix to use the explicit type if you prefer that.

Comment: @madreflection, thanks for the info. When you say "Visual Studio has a code fix", can you tell me where I can find it? Or a word I could use to google it? It helps to know what you are searching for.

Comment: Code fixes are presented by Visual Studio with the "..." under the portion of code it can fix (e.g., under `var`). Put the cursor on "`var`" and  press `Ctrl+.` or `Alt+Enter` to show the menu of code fixes. Look for "Use explicit type instead of 'var'", which will likely be the first one in the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @madreflection for sharing the knowledge.

As I'm using the 2 variables in multiple places, I extracted them as Static variables.

```
using EXCEL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    internal class clsMacros
    {
        //GLOBAL VARIABLES
        static RibbonMain RIBBON = Globals.Ribbons.RibbonMain;
        static EXCEL.Application APPLICATION = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

        public static void GetStatus()
        {
            RIBBON.chkCalculation.Checked = (APPLICATION.Calculation == EXCEL.XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic);
            RIBBON.chkScreenUpdating.Checked = APPLICATION.ScreenUpdating;
            RIBBON.chkEvents.Checked = APPLICATION.EnableEvents;
            RIBBON.chkDisplayAlerts.Checked = APPLICATION.DisplayAlerts;        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` should work fine, let the compiler figure out the type:

```cs
    var R = Globals.Ribbons.RibbonMain;
    var A = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    
    R.chkCalculation.Checked = (A.Calculation == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic);
    R.chkScreenUpdating.Checked = A.ScreenUpdating;
    R.chkEvents.Checked = A.EnableEvents;
    R.chkDisplayAlerts.Checked = A.DisplayAlerts;
```